# Android and responding to bad authentication credentials

Tags: android, authentication

I'm doing something like:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10*1000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10*1000);
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

to receive a JSON string at `url`.

This works fine when the authentication credentials I enter are correct and set with

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(loginNameString, passwordString.toCharArray());
    }
});
```

However, when I intentionally supply bad credentials the request of course fails but the app eventually just times out; where and how can I handle this event to notify the user and return control to her - is a there a hook?

**
Edit - I placed `System.out.println("hello!");` in my `getPasswordAuthentication()` override; this is being called over and over even after multiple failures due to bad credentials.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: HttpsUrlConnection with Authenticator for Basic Authentication iterates forever when password is wrong (on 401 response)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808301/android-httpsurlconnection-with-authenticator-for-basic-authentication-iterates)

Answer (score 0):

My way of dealing with this connection / authentification issues is by surrounding them with a :

```
try 
{
     //your connection attempt
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 //something goes wrong, handling the situation... for example :
     error = true;
}
if (error)
{
     //return control and notify the user, with a toast an alertDialog or whatever
}
```

It is ugly but it usually works... someone here surely has a better solution.

***EDIT*** :
Maybe this link will help : http://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/password-auth-http

Comment: I'm surrounding with try/catch. The connection just doesn't seem to time out even.

Comment: Thanks - this is part of what I'm doing already. I throttled down the connection time out from 5secs to 0.5secs to force a time out. I'm catching this exception, and control is back to the user as it should be. However, I'd like to do something similar if the user supplies bad credentials - and I still can't. Hmm.