# HttpsURLConnection not returning 401 in Android

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, http-status-code-401, httpsurlconnection

I've run into what seems to be a very strange problem. I'm using the HttpsURLConnection class in my Android app, and doing authentication using the Authenticator class.

I can connect to a web service with inputted username and password, and get a JSON response back. If I enter valid credentials this works absolutely fine and I get the returned response. However if I give it invalid credentials then then I never get a response and the my Async Task (that's running the code) never completes.

The code that is doing the connection is as follows:

```
private static String retrieveStream(String url) throws SocketTimeoutException {

    String streamContent = "";
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {

        Log.d("Connection", "Connecting to: " + url);

        Log.d("Connection", "Opening connection");
        urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        Log.d("Connection", "Setting connect timeout");
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        Log.d("Connection", "Setting read timeout");
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        Log.d("Connection", "Setting Allow All certs (because this is just testing)");
        urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());

        Log.d("Connection", "Connection Response: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode() + " " + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());

        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            streamContent = readStreamFromConnection(urlConnection);
            Log.d("Connection", "Returned content is: " + streamContent);
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "MalformedURLException thrown in retrieveStream: " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "IOException thrown in retrieveStream for " + url + " : " + e);
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return streamContent;
}
```

If I run this with invalid credentials this is what I get in the logs:

```
07-30 15:52:57.040: DEBUG/Connection(16000): Connecting to: https://webservice-that-i-use
07-30 15:52:57.040: DEBUG/Connection(16000): Opening connection
07-30 15:52:57.040: DEBUG/Connection(16000): Setting connect timeout
07-30 15:52:57.040: DEBUG/Connection(16000): Setting read timeout
07-30 15:52:57.040: DEBUG/Connection(16000): Setting Allow All certs (because this is just testing)
```

Then it just hangs here until I force stop the app or redeploy. I don't get any exceptions or ANRs.

It seems that I have the exact same problem as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808301/android-httpsurlconnection-with-authenticator-for-basic-authentication-iterates) but it was never answered. Does anyone have any ideas of why this happens? How I can get the connection to timeout on invalid credentials with HttpsURLConnection?

Any help would be appreciated. I should also note that my colleague has this working fine in iOS so it's not a server issue. This is running with the ICS SDK on a Asus Transformer TF101.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I have the same exact problem. I did not get any answers either. The exception I get is "Returned authorization is not challenge", etc, which means credentials is not correct. But there is no way to handle this. any luck?

Comment: @KevinRave the only way I managed is outlined in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/3731666