# Android HttpURLConnection- easiest way to trust all hosts?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection, authenticator

I'm trying to hit an https site through an Android client:

```
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            Log.d("Connection", myurl);
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            Log.d("Connection", "Connecting...");
            conn.connect();
```

The `connect` call is throwing an exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

EDIT: I'm told the site is using a self-signed certificate, and since this is only a prototype I just need to trust all hosts so it will work.  Can someone point me toward a simple example of doing this?  The code I've seen online gets quite complicated, I just want to do a hacky bypass of any verification.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the password you are supplying is correct?  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808301/android-httpsurlconnection-with-authenticator-for-basic-authentication-iterates) suggests that the connection can appear to hang if the password is incorrect.

Comment: I'll check it out, but yes the credentials are the same I'm using on iOS

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a new .csr with the right Organizational Unit Name and Common Name
Hope you are using HTTPS in your URL.

Comment: this is just a prototype, I don't think they're going to pay for a proper certificate at this point, so I just want to bypass any validation